# Считать и вывести таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Формат ввода:**

`n` и `m` - параметры таблицы в одной строке через пробел. n - число строк. m - число столбцов.
Затем, n строк по m чисел.

**Формат вывода:**

таблица `n` на `m` из чисел.

Как это реализовать? Я умею только когда элементы таблицы вводятся один за другим. Я не очень разбираюсь, но мне нужно, чтобы никакие дополнительные пакеты не использовались.

Comment: приведите пример кода

Comment: опубликуйте что у вас есть, что вы пробовали или что вы умеете.

Answer (score 3):

Пожалуйста:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())

a =  [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(m):
    a[i][j] = int(input())

for row in a: 
      for x in row: 
          print ( "{:4d}".format(x), end = "" ) 
      print ()
```

Answer (score 3):

Если позарез нужны какие-то проверки на правильность ввода - сделай сам, это не сложно

```
n, m = int(input('n: ')), int(input('m: '))

matrix = []

# вводим строки
for row in range(n):
    matrix.append(input(f'Row #{row+1}: ').split()) # разбиваем строку по пробелам и добавляем в матрицу
# выводим матрицу на экран

for row in matrix:
    print(*row)
```